# Did Papahānaumoku die?

Tags: polynesian

[Papahānaumoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papah%C4%81naumoku) is the Polynesian mother island goddess. While looking her up on Wikipedia, I see this line:

> Papanuihanaumoku, also known as Papa and Papatuanuku died in Waieri, Tahiti.

I Googled this, and came up with at least two other sources for this ([1](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Papah%C4%81naumoku)) ([2](https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Papah%C4%81naumoku)), but they all seem to say *exactly* the same thing, and I'm not sure I can trust this.

**Did Papahānaumoku die?**

Answer (score 8):

Sort of.

This particular sentence was added by an unregistered user, who also wrote that:

> Papa is one of my ancestors. She was the daughter of Kuaniehu . . . She was certainly not a God, her descendants from her and her husbands were the Ariki lines (High ranking Nobles) of Hawaii, Rarotonga, Aitutaki and the Maori.

The first bit has since been removed from the article. But from this, it is evident that this user is referring to the Papa who was a great-great...great-grand-daughter of [Hawaii'loa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiiloa). She is said to have married an alternating series of Hawaiian and Tahitian chiefs, namely, Wakea, Te-rii-fanau, Waia, and Te-rii-aumai, and was hence the progenitor of chiefs of both island systems.

> It is thus on account of her being the mother of chiefs, both here [Hawaii] and in Tahiti, that she is called Papa Nui Hanau Moku. She is said to have been a comely, handsome woman, very fair and  almost white. Papa is said to have travelled eight times between Tahiti and Hawaii, and died in a place called Waieri, in Tahiti, during the time of Nanakehili, the fifth in descent from her and Wakea.
>
> <sup>Cartwright, Bruce. "The Legend of Hawaii-loa." *The Journal of the Polynesian Society* 38.2 (150 (1929): 105-121.</sup>

This Papa was also identified as Huhune or Haumea. Haumea is of course also the Hawaiian [goddess of childbirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haumea_(mythology)), for whom a [dwarf planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haumea) was named a few years ago. She is sometimes identified as a manifestation of Papahānaumoku the Earth Mother, or as her human incarnation. But there's a great deal of confusion.

A Haumea appears in the [*Kumulipo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumulipo) with Wakea, as the progenitors of the Hwaiian people. Here she is said to have re-incarnated several times to marry her sons and grandsons for six generations, until Kio saw through her. In this version, it's unclear what happened to her after that.

> Many forms had this woman Haumea
>   Great Haumea was mysterious
>   Mysterious was Haumea in the way she lived
>   She lived with her grandchildren
>   She slept with her children
>   Slept with her child Kauakahi as [?] the wife Kuaimehani
>   Slept with her grandchild Kaua-huli-honua
>   As [?] his wife Huli-honua
>   Slept with her grandchild Haloa
>   As [?] his wife Hinamanoʻuluaʻe
>   Slept with her grandchild Waia as [?] his wife Huhune
>   Slept with her grandchild Hinanalo as [?] his wife Haunuʻu
>   Slept with her grandchild Nanakahili as [?] his wife Haulani
>   Slept with her grandchild Wailoa as [?] his wife Hikapua- neiea
>   Kiʻo was born, Haumea was recognized
>   Haumea was seen to be shriveled
>   Cold and undesirable
>
> <sup>Beckwith, Martha Warren, ed. *The Kumulipo: a Hawaiian Creation Chant.* University of Hawaii Press, 1981.</sup>

The above source is also available online at the Ulukau Hawaiian Electronic Library [**here**](http://www.ulukau.org/elib/cgi-bin/library?c=beckwit2&l=en).

In another tradition, Haumea was killed with a net by [Kaulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaulu), a symbolic subjugation of nature by agriculture.